# how to make text not overlap it's container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have this code:

```
<li style="padding: 23px 5px 23px 19px; width: 100%;">
  <div style="min-width: 50%;">
    Email Address
  </div>
  <div style="min-width: 50%;">
    Antonina.Russel47@gmail.com
  </div>
</li>
```

and the result looks like this: 
[image]
as you can see on the bottom cell, i would want the text that overlap to come on bottom. i tried flex-wrap: nowrap; with no success. Help?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Comment: can you post your css and the ul part please

Comment: Try `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css

div{ white-space:normal; word-break: break-all}

Comment: Feel great to hear that... Welcome-i am